# Airpush for Android - What is fact and what a myth?

Tags: android, airpush

I read different perspectives on Airpush for Android.

A few people write that

- it generated very good revenue
- it was the only pay per view - network for mobile phones
- Apps using Airpush were banned because Airpush exhibited malware-like behaviour

Please share details with sources:

- What is fact and what a myth?
- What changed from myth to fact or fact to myth?

Comment: Is this an ad for Airpush or a question?

Comment: Whatever it is, it isn't programming related.  Voting to close.

Comment: Don't use airpush - They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)

Answer (score 16):

Airpush is considered a <strike>**malware**</strike> adware because when app X (with Airpush) is installed, it could show ads to you anytime and anywhere - application X does not have to be running. Also there isn't a way for the user to find out which application is sending the ads.

*EDIT* - I have multiple applications on the market and I constantly receive generic Airpush salesman letters to join their network to my developer account email (they are probably scraping Google play for emails and spamming developers).

Comment: can you please tell me that how much it pay for just adds display on your screen and for click on the adds. please let elaborate me that how it pay and how much for each adds,click and install. pleae

Comment: Thank you so much Indrek Kõue. Now I know why my application is ditected as malware by ESET Mobile Security & Antivirus. I will remove that code as so many users are complaining for that.

Answer (score 4):

No Airpush apps are being banned by Google.  This is a myth.
It's also not considered malware...
There are other networks that run the same services as Airpush.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Airpush representative. Some answers to your questions:

1) It is a fact that Airpush developers earn 10x - 30x higher than traditional in-app ads. This is why the platform is growing extremely fast with over 10,000 live apps and adding 100+ per day. We recently gave some growth statistics and charts in [this interview](http://www.androidauthority.com/follow-up-interview-with-airpush-developers-and-android-users-both-win-32072/) with Android Authority. We also post the previous day's CPM and fill rate on our website so you can see the actual data.

2)  Airpush is absolutely not adware or malware -- it is simply an alternative form of mobile advertising. A **permanent** opt-out link is tagged on each and every ad, and users can easily uninstall the application display Airpush ads. To determine which application shows Airpush ads, the user can simply check his Recent Apps by holding the Home button, and also the application name is displayed post-click in the upper left of the Webview container.  Also, Google plans to include capability for multiple click events within items in the notification tray, at which point we will be able to have a 1 click opt-out versus the current 2 click process. Still, it's a very simple process to optout today, which isn't something any other networks offer.

3) To our knowledge, we are not the only CPM-based (ie; paid for impressions) mobile ad network. Some traditional mobile ad networks like Mobfox have a CPM product, where you get paid for impressions rather than CPC-based.

4) Regarding getting banned for using Airpush -- we have over 10,000 live Android apps using the Airpush SDK. There was only 1 developer who got temporarily suspended (APNDroid), and he was immediately unsuspended within 24 hours. His temporary suspension was due to an incorrect installation of the Airpush SDK which caused his app to crash.

Comment: `...To determine which application shows Airpush ads, the user can simply check his Recent Apps by holding the Home button...` - when user has multiple active application, then there is no way to tell which one is sending the Ad (other than clicking the ad)?

Comment: opt-outs are illegal in some countries. Only explicit opt-in (in some country even only double-opt-ins) are allowed by law. So technically it is a malware, because the Notification bar is not like advertisement in an app, where it's obvious. The Notification spam doesn't show it's origin and is more similar to email, so same roles as for email spam applies

Why? Because same as mail, you can receive the notification spam every time even if you don't use an app (equal to browsing a website). So opt-outs are illegal in most of the world

Comment: It's also bullshit that you can easily find it out. Most users don't know that it's visible in the recently used apps list. All you do is trying to hide it and get as much clicks as possible. 

It's very easy to implement an Dialog which displays "This advertisement is displayed by <APP NAME>. Do you want to visit the sponsors site? [yes]/[no]". But you don't do this because 95% of your profit comes from users who don't know this are ads and accidently clicks on it. It's not only spam and malware, it's pure scam. You scam your advertisers by exploiting users who accidently click it.

Comment: can you please give some links about the fact that it's illegal on some countries ?

Comment: German laws for example specifically demand an out-in, as an out-out is not sufficient enough to prevent people from receiving unwanted spam. It's not limited to emails, but generally everything where something is sent to the user or some of his data is about to be saved.

Even single-opt-ins are dangerous (from company point of view) because someone could sign your email address for some (or many) newsletters. Companies which send unwanted spam to people can be fined up to 50.000 EUR. In Germany we're very picky about privacy

Comment: This also makes all of those SMS subscription scam invalidate in Germany, because they use single opt-in (i.e. visiting a website or clicking on a banner) to "conclude a subscription contract". 

Only contracts which were done by explicitly notifying the user about the subscriptions costs and sending an SMS with a validation code/Link which as to be clicked on to finish the contract are valid. Everything else is considered scam and people don't have to pay for this kind of contracts

Comment: Tseng, supply a link, where it specifically states that notifications are considered equal to e-mails under german law, or better a link to the german text of that law.

Comment: what about the new rules of google for ads : http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html ?  they now specifically write "Ads must not simulate or impersonate system notifications or warnings." , while airpush puts ads as system notifications...

Comment: YOU DO NOT PAY UP !!!! CARFUL DEVS - THEY DONT PAY!!!! I'M FURIOUS WITH U ITS A SCAM

Answer (score 0):

Airpush is not considered Malware nor were any apps using Airpush banned from the Android Network. There are many many apps that use push notification, including Google+, Facebook, OKCupid, POF, Sprint and many others. We have had push notification for almost two years.

On a side note, there is a small number of developers [two in particular] that do not like the Airpush idea and they spam every site and every app they have time to, repeatedly changing their user name, to discredit Airpush as well as several other 'targeted' networks. Unaware, that their IP addresses are recorded every time they spam the sites and apps.

Airpush is great for developers and advertising monetization has proven more profitable than selling the app for .99 USD.

Comment: Kazuko Ando, Where did you get this information from?